# Test vectors for FF1/FF3-1

Tags: encryption, implementation, format-preserving, test-vectors

I'm working on a C implementation of the FF1 and FF3-1 format-preserving encryption [algorithms](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38Gr1-draft.pdf), [here](https://github.com/ubiqsecurity/ubiq-fpe-c).

For FF1, NIST provides test vectors, [here](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/FF1samples.pdf); however, none of the test vectors is crafted such that `d` is ever greater than 8, such that Step 6iii is never executed in the code. Does anyone know of any test vectors that exercise that part of the algorithm?

For FF3-1, I have not found any "official" test vectors. Is anyone aware of any that have been published?

Comment: If you search the PDF then you will find `d is 12`, i.e. there are test vectors for $d=12>8$ for FF1.

There are no test vector for FF3-1 as in the case of FF1, here what I could find; [IETF draft](https://pages.nist.gov/ACVP/draft-celi-acvp-symmetric.html#property_grid_misc) on NIST pages.

Comment: You're correct. I should've been more clear that I'm looking for a vector where d >= 16 which would cause the algorithm to have to calculate subsequent blocks after the initial block R in step 6iii of FF1. Thanks for the link.